# Is there any way to substitute environment variables in playframework's application.conf?

Tags: playframework

Is there any way to use environment variables in the play! application.conf file? Something like this:

```
%prod.db.url=${env.DATABASE_JDBC_URL}
%prod.db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
%prod.jpa.ddl=validate
```

I don't want to hardcode the URL in my application.conf because it contains credentials that the developer should not have access to.

Comment: I don't understand how you can hide this information? If you have access to the env variable, it means you can read its value, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`${ENV_VARIABLE_KEY}` does resolve any variables that are set in your environment. you don't have to specify "env." prefix unless it's part of your key.

Comment: Yup. This is a new feature added to play after I posted my original question. Very cool.

Answer (score 12):

All variables within ${} are resolved using the following sources:

- ${application.path} equivalent to Play.applicationPath.getAbsolutePath()
- ${play.path} equivalent to Play.frameworkPath.getAbsolutePath()
- any other comes from System.getProperty.

So you could add these as **-Dkey=name** parameters when launching Play! with your secret credentials specific to your environment.

Comment: I tried adding the first bullet point, but a run-time exception occurred: `Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${application.path}`

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. My solution :

- let application.conf with only properties for local development and store it in a VCS (SVN, Git, ...) for your dev team
- add a line in the application.conf file : "@include.prod=prod.conf"
- the file prod.conf contains only %prod.* properties
- create the file prod.conf directly on prod server (or store it in a different VCS than your application, where only allowed people can read/write it)

It works fine for me.

It just adds a message for the dev team when the application starts :

ex: 20 mai 2011 21:09:16 play.Logger warn ATTENTION: Missing include: @include.prod

Really not a problem. Just inform your dev team that this message is not a problem and to not delete the "@include.prod" line in application.conf

Hope it helps