# Any way to run play framework (1.x) auto-test on different databases?

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

In local development I want to connect to my personal database for auto-test. In the build farm, I want to connect to a different database for auto-test. How can that be done?

Play seems very flexible with configuration, except with running auto-tests. Have I missed a secret special trick somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/FeCaXXe4En8)...

Test and auto-test always uses test as ID, so you can't overwrite the value depending on which test environment you are on. I am not aware if this bug has been fixed, but I couldnt find an associated bug or fix on lighthouse.

You can use environment variables in your `application.conf`, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073720/is-there-any-way-to-substitute-environment-variables-in-playframeworks-applicat), which means you can pass in the db name using a `-Dvariable`. So

`play auto-test -Dtestdb=your-cit-db`

then in you application.conf, you would do

`%test.db.name={testdb}`